# What do I need to do to finish a roof with exposed rafters on a shed

Tags: roof, roofing

I have a shed as pictured that had never been finished completely.  As such the shed has a lot of dust debris, etc getting in that should not be. What do I need to do to finish the shed. Should I be concerned about the exposed wood / rafters?

[image: Unfinished Shed]

Far as I can tell I am going to need to add:

- Facia Board
- Soffit board
- Drip Edge

Is there anything else I need to add or be concerned about?

[image: Roof Parts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram you showed is fine. That is really all you need to do. I might add a small strip of 1X2 along the wall as a nailer for the soffit.  The only alternative would be substituting a vented soffit panel for the solid soffit. Using a vented soffit would help a little in exiting hot air and give a bit of ventilation. Best used with a ridge vent for really good ventilation, but better than nothing if used alone.